# How can I revise the velocity that ROS set for robot navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone.

I am fresh to use ROS.
I am now able to control a mobile robot with teleop, and have already built a room-environment map by using gmapping.

After that, I tried to make the robot to perform a navigation task.
I first pressed "pose estimation" of rviz'GUI and then pointed an approximate pose for the robot in rviz's map.
Then pressed "Nav Goal", and followed by telling robot a position to go.

And the problem occurs, the robot began moving and sometimes it just tremble while moving on the way to the goal position.
Someone suggested that it might be due to the velocity that ROS configured.

So, how i can revise it or do something else.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12664/how-can-i-revise-the-velocity-that-ros-set-for-robot-navigation/) by [letmoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/1610/letmoon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-01-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide) tutorial for navigation configuration, and [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) tutorial for set up and configuration.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you set up the navigation stack according to the tutorial? Then you should have a file called base_local_planner_params.yaml or some such. You can add limits there for the robot's movement. The parameters are described on this page:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/base_local_planner

---

Originally posted by [raahlb](https://answers.ros.org/users/966/raahlb/) with karma: 317 on 2012-01-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2